# To make something opaque = opaquen?

Tags: single-word-requests

To make something opaque is to 'opaquen'?

How about to make something transparent? Is it 'transparentize'?

---

**Edit 1**
This is for a computer code library that manipulates colors. I have verbs to describe the actions like `Brighten` and `Saturate`, but I also want to find a nice words to describe making something more or less opaque.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's *[opacify](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/opacify?r=66)*:

> to cause to become opaque.

It sounds a bit awkward/made up, but the meaning is unambiguous.

*Make transparent* is more difficult. *Clarify* could work in certain limited contexts, but not in yours, I think. Unfortunately, I think a multi-word construction such as SetTransparency is your only choice here.

Comment: I think *opacify* is a good option, I wish I had thought of that one. It's programming: nobody cares if it's a real or conventional word, as long as it is reasonably concise and its meaning is clear.

Comment: I hope we can opacify the oinsurgents without offending the opacifists.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: ooffending, actually. :P

Comment: de-opacify?  Is it the reverse of opacification?

Comment: The OED also attest *opacate*, as in this citation: 1890 H. Frederic *Lawton Girl* 20 ― Eyes··dimmed and opacated by the effects of dissipation.

Answer (score 5):

Translucent is between opaque and transparent, so... Translucify?

(As a bonus, it sounds bad-ass, like an album from a band called Translucifer!)

Comment: Translucence is another property aside from opacity, it has a dispersion component.Or, hold it. Opacity is a combination of transmittance and dispersion. Still not the same things.

Comment: Love "translucify" - I need just this word right now and nothing like it exists... If I weren't writing in the voice of an 8-year-old I would use it right now...

Answer (score 2):

*Opaquen* is not a word. According to the *Random House Dictionary*, opaque is an acceptable word as an adjective, a noun (i.e. something that is opaque), or as a verb (i.e. to cause to be opaque).

However, people reading your code (undrestandably) might not realize that you are using *opaque* as a verb, so it probably is not the best option. I would reccommend `SetOpacity`.

Comment: `SetOpacity` would work if I was actually setting the opacity. This code *changes* the opacity by an amount (like a percent). I more or less move the opacity towards a certain direction (either totaly transparent or totaly opaque), so I am going with `MoreOpaque` and `LessOpaque` despite my dislike to this.

Comment: How about `ChangeOpacity`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any verbs for your uses of *to make something xxx*.  If there are any, they will likely not be known to your average audience, so it's best to stick with the *to make* form for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Thats the problem when you are trying to use common language for programming. I don't want to write a `MakeColorMoreOpaque(amount)` function, but a `Opaquen(amount)` function.

Comment: How about *IncreaseOpacity*?

Comment: *IncreaseOpacity* only works if you are always wanting to increase it. A better name would be *SetOpacity*.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen *opaquen* used; in its place, I've simply seen *opaque* verbed.  For the inverse operation I've seen *deopaque*.

Comment: This is probably because the *-en* suffix is usually used with monosyllabic stems.

Comment: I've seen *opaque* as a verb also, but it is not recognized as a verb by all dictionaries (not by Merriam Webster, at least)

Comment: @Kosmonaut, more specifically, _-en_ is subject to the phonosemantic constraint that it can only be used to derive verbs from _monosyllabic adjectives that end in an obstruent_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I'm not really seeing where semantics enters into it; I would characterize it as a morphophonological constraint.  Also, note that there is at least one exception (that I can think of) to requirement that it be monosyllabic in *awaken*.

Comment: I suppose you can call it that—the semantic bit was the word class restraint. Is it morphology or semantics that decide whether ‘black’ is a noun or an adjective, for example? ‘Awaken’ is not an example of the productive suffix _-en_, but a merger of several Old English verbs (some of which contain the suffix, and some not), and its ultimate base is still a monosyllabic adjective, only with a preverb before it; similarly, ‘unblacken’ also works okay.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are making opaque.

Some words that can be used include: obfuscate, solidify, cloud, darken, muddle, and confuse.

Antonyms include: evanesce, clarify, purify, and lighten.